# using getDefinitionByName correctly

Tags: actionscript-3

here is my code line :

```
  new (getDefinitionByName(String( "mypackage.MyDynamicClass"  )) as Class) ;
```

This generates an error : mypackage.MyDynamicClass is not defined.

I googled and found a solution :  Use the name of the class in the import statement.

So,

```
  import mypackage.MyDynamicClass 
  new (getDefinitionByName(String( "mypackage.MyDynamicClass"  )) as Class) ;
```

It worked!!!

but, I am not satisfied with this solution, as it really violates  the benefit of a dynamic class. If i know the name of the class ( in import ), then why i would be using it as a string ?

Any alternatives to make dynamic loading of classes work ?

Vishwas

Comment: Given the restriction in bounty request, the answer is negative, you NEED to have a hard reference to that class somewhere in order for the compiler to include the class definition into your project. But, you only need that reference once, anywhere. I've used static array like `static const dummy:Array=[OneClass,TwoClass,ThreeClass];` You make one array containing all the classes you want, and use `getDefinitionByName()` as you want.

Comment: hmm..just hoping if someone might have some solution.
I need "no declaration", because class name is coming from XML.

Comment: Add every possible entry into your dummy array, and use whatever is transferred via XML as its parameter, should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use a abstract factory
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern
Its a very flexible way to create objects without knowing wich class you are going to instantiate.

Is in this abstract factory class in wich you will need to import all the clases you might create objects from, this will not require you to import all clases in your main class but you will still need to import the abstract factory and the interface to communicate with your new objects.

Here is a quick example:

```
/*
The interface you will use to communicate with your objects
*/
InterfaceForAllMyClasses.as
public interface InterfaceForAllMyClasses
{
    public function callMe();
    public function callMe2();
}

/*
Your Classes wich implement the interface
*/
Class1.as
import mypackage.InterfaceForAllMyClasses;
public class Class1 implements InterfaceForAllMyClasses
{
    public function callMe() { trace("called Class1"); }
    public function callMe2() { trace("called Class1 too"); }
}

Class2.as
import mypackage.InterfaceForAllMyClasses;
public class Class1 implements InterfaceForAllMyClasses
{
    public function callMe() { trace("called Class2"); }
    public function callMe2() { trace("called Class2 too"); }
}

/*
The Abstract Factory
*/
AbstractFactory.as
import mypackage.InterfaceForAllMyClasses;
public class AbstractFactory
{
    public function giveMeObject(classNumber:Number):InterfaceForAllMyClasses
    {
        switch(classNumber)
        {
            case 0: return(new Class1()); break;
            case 1: return(new Class2()); break;
            // for any new class that you add you must add a case entry here
        }
    }
}

/*
Your Program
*/
import mypackage.InterfaceForAllMyClasses;
import mypackage.AbstractFactory;
MyProgram.as
public class MyProgram
{
    var abstractFactory:AbstractFactory = new AbstractFactory();

    public function main()
    {
        var x:InterfaceForAllMyClasses=AbstractFactory.giveMeObject(0);
        var y:InterfaceForAllMyClasses=AbstractFactory.giveMeObject(1);

        x.callMe();
        x.callMe2();
        y.callMe();
        y.callMe2();        
    }
}
```

If you cant import the classes from your main application because they are declared in external modules (swfs), then you can make each module as an Abstract Factory, here is an example:

```
Interfaces/IModuleInterface.as

package Interfaces
    {
        public interface IModuleInterface
        {
            function giveMeObject(classNumber:Number):IObjectInterface;
        }
    }

Interfaces/IObjectInterface.as

package Interfaces
    {
        public interface IObjectInterface
        {
            function callMe():void;
            function callMeToo():void;
        }
    }

Modules/ModuleOne.mxml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"         implements="Interfaces.IModuleInterface">
        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import Interfaces.IObjectInterface;
                public function giveMeObject(classNumber:Number):IObjectInterface
                {
                    switch(classNumber)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            trace("ModuleOne: Instantiating 1");
                            return(new ModuleOneClassOne()); 
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            trace("ModuleOne: Instantiating 2");
                            return(new ModuleOneClassTwo()); 
                            break;
                    }
                    return(null);
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>
        <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        </fx:Declarations>
        <s:Label x="10" y="10" text="Module One Loaded"/>
    </s:Module>

Modules/ModuleOneClassOne.as

    package Modules
    {
        import Interfaces.IObjectInterface;

        public class ModuleOneClassOne implements IObjectInterface
        {
            public function ModuleOneClassOne()
            {
                trace("ModuleOneClassOne: Instantiated");
            }

            public function callMe():void
            {
                trace("ModuleOneClassOne: called callMe()");
            }

            public function callMeToo():void
            {
                trace("ModuleOneClassOne: called callMeToo()");
            }
        }
    }

Modules/ModuleOneClassTwo.as

    package Modules
    {
        import Interfaces.IObjectInterface;

        public class ModuleOneClassTwo implements IObjectInterface
        {
            public function ModuleOneClassTwo()
            {
                trace("ModuleOneClassTwo: Instantiated");
            }

            public function callMe():void
            {
                trace("ModuleOneClassTwo: called callMe()");
            }

            public function callMeToo():void
            {
                trace("ModuleOneClassTwo: called callMeToo()");
            }
        }
    }

AbstractFactoryInModules.mxml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   width="345" height="200">

        <fx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import Interfaces.IModuleInterface;
                import Interfaces.IObjectInterface;

                import mx.events.ModuleEvent;
                protected var module:IModuleInterface;
                protected var object:IObjectInterface;

                protected function ButtonLoadSwf_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    loader.unloadModule();
                    loader.url=moduleUrl.text;
                }

                protected function loader_readyHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void
                {
                    this.module = (loader.child) as IModuleInterface;
                }

                protected function ButtonCreateObject_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    this.object = this.module.giveMeObject(Number(TClassNumber.text));
                }

                protected function BCallMe_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    this.object.callMe();
                }

                protected function BCallMeToo_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    this.object.callMeToo();
                }
            ]]>
        </fx:Script>

        <fx:Declarations>
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        </fx:Declarations>
        <s:Button id="ButtonLoadSwf" x="236" y="10" width="99" label="Load SWF"
                  click="ButtonLoadSwf_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="ButtonCreateObject" x="150" y="108" label="Create Object"
                  click="ButtonCreateObject_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:TextInput id="TClassNumber" x="96" y="107" width="46" text="1"/>
        <s:ModuleLoader x="10" y="39" width="325" height="60" id="loader" ready="loader_readyHandler(event)">
        </s:ModuleLoader>
        <s:TextInput id="moduleUrl" x="10" y="10" width="218" text="Modules/ModuleOne.swf"/>
        <s:Button id="BCallMe" x="96" y="137" width="150" label="callMe"
                  click="BCallMe_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="BCallMeToo" x="96" y="166" width="150" label="callMeToo"
                  click="BCallMeToo_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: The problem is, i still see need of new Class1() and new Class2() before compilation. In my case the swf is already compiled, so there is no scope of adding class declaration. The name of class comes directly from XML, and the body of that class is present in the "swf" going to be called.

Comment: Ok, then you can make each of your swfs to be a abstract factory, but make sure that all of them use also a interface, here is an example:

Comment: Check the edit please, its an example using Flex, all you need to do is to make use of the same interface trough all your objects.
Note that using interfaces is not the only way to solve your problem, but this will avoid memory leaks and a lot of complexity

Comment: Seems promising to me. Thnx! :)

Answer (score 5):

Take look at this article: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/loading-classes-dynamically-in-actionscript-3.html 
You cannot avoid including the classes you need at the runtime. You can always use:

```
import mypackage.*
```

Be aware at the fact that including all the classes in the package might increase the code size.

Comment: I would recommend carefully reading that article, since just importing the class or package could not be enough ;)

Comment: I would also recommend creating a package containing only the dynamicly loaded classes, so you do not compile any other unnecessary classes.

Comment: @Mircea, this seems much closer to what i need. But unfortunately it requires mxmlc. But i am using Flash IDE

Answer (score 3):

It definitely not violating dynamic loading of Class because of our compiler detect unused class/import statement in our project then get rid of those class file for packed as swc or swf so the advantage of our final output file size can reduce.

Unless few times unable reduce file size.

Probably you know what are the class you are trying to load via getDefinitionByName() before make sure that class available in `IncludeClass.as`

For better way, you can import statement for your project

```
package
{
    public class IncludeClasses
    {
        import com.abc.db.Database; Database;
        import com.abc.RemoteLogTarget; RemoteLogTarget;
        import com.abc.LocalLogTarget; LocalLogTarget;
        import com.abc.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler; GlobalExceptionHandler;
        import com.abc.utils.NetConnectionMonitor; NetConnectionMonitor;
    }
}
```

Stil you want to use your way better you can try with compiler options.